# Sequencing and overriding tasks in SBT

Tags: scala, heroku, playframework, sbt, sbt-native-packager

Quick summary: I'm trying to wait in the top-level project for all SBT submodules to build, then remove their `target` directories. Top-level application aggregates all submodules, they won't be deployed separately but only as a bundle with classpath dependencies, while duplicated libraries in submodules blow up the size of the whole package and the slug goes over Heroku limit.

Technically, I'm trying to [actually use this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/reducing-the-slug-size-of-play-2-x-applications#using-sbt-to-clean-build-artifacts) - I'm trying to add a 'cleanup' task that would run after `stage`. The solution from link above doesn't seem to work for me (Play 2.4, SBT 0.13.5), the error says it better than I can:

```
build.sbt:50: error: reference to stage is ambiguous;
it is imported twice in the same scope by
import _root_.com.typesafe.sbt.packager.universal.UniversalPlugin.autoImport._
and import $52e59eb09172b3222f9e._
stage := {
```

Assuming I have my cleanup task:

```
val stageCleanupTask = taskKey[Unit]("Clean after stage task")

stageCleanupTask := {
  val log = streams.value.log
  if (sys.env.getOrElse("POST_STAGE_CLEAN", "false").equals("true")) {
    log.info("Cleaning submodules' target directories")
    sbt.IO.delete(baseDirectory.value / "modules" / "a" / "target")
    sbt.IO.delete(baseDirectory.value / "modules" / "b" / "target")
    sbt.IO.delete(baseDirectory.value / "modules" / "c" / "target")
  }
}
```

and I'm tring to override `stage`:

```
stage := {
  val f = (stage in Universal).value
  stageCleanupTask.value
  f
}
```

It seems to be simply wrong, since both tasks run concurrently.
SBT doesn't really make it easy either, I didn't find much in the official documentation, so I was just playing around:

- `stage.flatMap` expects a function that returns a `Task[U]`, but `stageCleanupTask` is a `TaskKey[T]`, and `.value` doesn't work outside of very specific areas, so composition via something similar to `stage <<= stage.flatMap(f => stageCleanupTask.map(_ => f))` seems to be out of the question.
- `dependsOn` could only work as `stage <<= stage dependsOn stageCleanupTask`, which is the exact opposite of the dependency chain I want. `stageCleanupTask` should depend on `stage`, but the types won't match (`Task[Unit]` vs `Task[File]`)
- I was trying to experiment with composition inside overriden `stage`, as in:

  ```
  stage := {
      (stage in Universal).map(f => /*follow up*/ f).value
  }
  ```

  but that usually just slaps me in the face with `illegal dynamic dependency` or `illegal dynamic reference`

What would be the preferred way of sequencing SBT tasks?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but as far as reducing the slug size of your Heroku app goes, you could fork the buildpack and modify this section to include your `target` sub-dirs: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-scala/blob/master/bin/compile#L149-L171

Comment: I would also accept a PR for adding an SBT_POST_TASKS here: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-scala/blob/master/bin/compile#L109

Comment: @codefinger Thanks, I'll definitely look into SBT_POST_TASKS - no promises though, bash (especially robust scripts) is not my forte :)

Comment: I made the change. https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-scala/commit/fdaa1159b8f75909e55566b12a222afef486cf05 If you can open a ticket at http://help.heroku.com I can tell you how to use this branch of the buildpack and provide more info. I'd rather get the discussion out of this thread.

Comment: @codefinger SBT only solutions should be completely possible though ;) It was called `Simple Build Tool` for a reason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace following code

```
stage := {
  val f = (stage in Universal).value
  stageCleanupTask.value
  f
}
```

By this one

```
import com.typesafe.sbt.packager.universal.UniversalPlugin.autoImport.Universal

stage := Def.taskDyn {
  val x = (stage in Universal).value
  Def.task {
    stageCleanupTask.value
    x
  }
}.value
```

That will lead to sequencing tasks and work as you expected.

Comment: How do you import `Universal` in this context?

Answer (score 7):

See http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Howto-Sequencing.html for how to sequence tasks.

So something like:

```
stage in Universal := Def.sequential(
  stage in Universal,
  stageCleanupTask
)
```

Comment: I up-voted this but after reviewing the actual code, I have second thoughts. This doesn't do what the OP requested. This is the actual signature of the method: `def sequential[A0, B](task0: Initialize[Task[A0]], last: Initialize[Task[B]]): Initialize[Task[B]]` which means it still returns the type of the second task you pass it, in this case `Unit`. This is incorrect since `stage` requires `sbt.File`.

Answer (score 5):

Let me start by saying that `baseDirectory.value / "modules" / "a" / "target"` is not the kind of path definition you want to use since it's much better to make use of the settings SBT provides you. What I recommend is using `(target in moduleName).value`.

As for your main question, I recommend you do this:

```
val stageCleanupTask = taskKey[sbt.File]("Clean after stage task")

lazy val root = project.in(file("."))
  ...
  .settings(
    stageCleanupTask := {
      val a = (stage in Universal).value
      val log = streams.value.log
      if (sys.env.getOrElse("POST_STAGE_CLEAN", "false").equals("true")) {
        log.info("Cleaning submodules' target directories")
        sbt.IO.delete((target in a).value)
        sbt.IO.delete((target in b).value)
        sbt.IO.delete((target in c).value)
      }
      a
    },
    stage <<= stageCleanupTask
```

I just tested in one of my own projects and it worked flawlessly.

---

### Edit 1

My battery is dying so I can't look into [this](http://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/docs/Tasks.html#andFinally) further but it might be the thing you're looking for.

Comment: This discussion is also fairly interesting: https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/1001

Comment: Oh, right, thanks for pointing out the `(target in module).value`. As for threading the cleanup just to return it at the very end - I thought there might be a dedicated, maybe more elegant solution, but I'll take it. Thanks! In the end, it means that if I change the `stageCleanupTask`, then either `<<=` or `Def.sequential` should work.

Comment: I take it back, `Def.sequential` still doesn't match all the types.