# How can I use sbt commands like clean and compile in my custom sbtplugin

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-plugin

I have the following, minimal, custom sbt plugin, where I'd like to implement (override) the standard `clean` command to do the same action as `myTask`.

```
package nigeleke.sbt

import sbt.*
import Keys.*

import scala.sys.process.*

object MyPlugin extends AutoPlugin {

  object autoImport {
    val myTask = taskKey[Unit]("Do something.")
  }

  import autoImport._

  override def requires = empty

  override def trigger = noTrigger

  override lazy val projectSettings = Seq(
    myTask := {
      println(s"project: ${thisProject.value.id}  plugins: ${thisProject.value.plugins}")
    },
    clean  := clean.dependsOn(myTask).value
  )

}
```

When I enable this plugin a client project, the `myTask` command works as expected. I would also like `clean` to invoke the same task, but no output is forthcoming:

```
> sbt
[info] welcome to sbt 1.8.2 (Eclipse Adoptium Java 17.0.6)
[info] loading global plugins from ... \.sbt\1.0\plugins
[info] loading settings for project sbt-example-client-build from plugins.sbt ...
[info] loading project definition from ... \sbt-example-client\project
[info] loading settings for project root from build.sbt,version.sbt ...
[info] set current project to sbt-example-client (in build file:/ ... /sbt-example-client/)
[info] sbt server started at local:sbt-server-c377c6b81cca5b432adb
[info] started sbt server
sbt:sbt-example-client> myTask
project: client  plugins: nigeleke.sbt.MyPlugin
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed 13 Apr 2023, 5:05:18 pm
sbt:sbt-example-client> clean
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed 13 Apr 2023, 5:05:21 pm
sbt:sbt-example-client>
```

I'm failing to find the correct syntax to invoke it, so any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: Did you try something like `clean := { myTask.value; clean.value }`? Your `dependsOn` would invoke the dependency only once and then cache the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that `clean` is defined in a default built-in sbt plugin  `JvmPlugin`

https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/v1.8.2/main/src/main/scala/sbt/plugins/JvmPlugin.scala#L44-L46

```
object JvmPlugin extends AutoPlugin {
  ...
  override lazy val projectSettings: Seq[Setting[_]] =
      ... ++
      Defaults.baseTasks ++    // (1)
      Defaults.compileBase ++  // (2)
      Defaults.defaultConfigs  // (3)
}
```

https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/v1.8.2/main/src/main/scala/sbt/Defaults.scala

```
object Defaults extends BuildCommon { 

  lazy val baseTasks: Seq[Setting[_]] = projectTasks ++ ...

  lazy val projectTasks: Seq[Setting[_]] = Seq(
    ...
    clean :=                                 // (1)
      Def.taskDyn(Clean.task(resolvedScoped.value.scope, full = true)).value,
    ...
  )

  def compileBase = ... ++ Seq(
    ...
    clean := clean.dependsOn(cleanIvy).value, // (2)
    ...
  )

  lazy val defaultConfigs: Seq[Setting[_]] =
    inConfig(Compile)(compileSettings) ++ 
    inConfig(Test)(testSettings) ++ ...

  lazy val compileSettings: Seq[Setting[_]] = configSettings + ...

  lazy val testSettings: Seq[Setting[_]] = configSettings ++ ...

  lazy val configSettings: Seq[Setting[_]] = ... ++ configTasks ++ ...

  lazy val configTasks: Seq[Setting[_]] = ... ++ Seq(
    ...
    clean := (compileOutputs / clean).value,  // (3)
    ...
  )
}
```

---

You can't disable `JvmPlugin` because in such case sbt can't build a project.

So in order to override `clean` you should make your plugin depend on `JvmPlugin` (otherwise `JvmPlugin` definition of `clean` overrides yours)

```
object MyPlugin extends AutoPlugin {
  ...

  override def requires = JvmPlugin
```

Then any of the following options works:

```
clean := clean.dependsOn(myTask).value
```

```
clean := {
  myTask.value
  clean.value
}
```

```
clean := Def.sequential(myTask, clean).value
```

---

[How can a default task be overridden from an AutoPlugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25247662/how-can-a-default-task-be-overridden-from-an-autoplugin)

https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Custom-Settings.html#Implementing+a+task

[SBT task dependsOn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41183255/sbt-task-dependson)

[SBT dependsOn usage - migration from 0.12 to 0.13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44657163/sbt-dependson-usage-migration-from-0-12-to-0-13)

[Per-project tasks in SBT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54393160/per-project-tasks-in-sbt)

[Sbt run command for multiple projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57806115/sbt-run-command-for-multiple-projects)

[Sequencing and overriding tasks in SBT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34841410/sequencing-and-overriding-tasks-in-sbt)

[How to exclude files in a custom clean task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24020437/how-to-exclude-files-in-a-custom-clean-task)

[How to execute clean task in dependent projects from a task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26218457/how-to-execute-clean-task-in-dependent-projects-from-a-task)